# Varnish http to https

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am new to varnish or programming in general. I want to setup http to https redirect for my domain.
Here's what I have so far

```
sub vcl_recv {

if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto != "https" || req.http.Scheme != "https"){
        error 750 "http to https";
 }


sub vcl_error {

if (obj.status == 750){
   set obj.status = 302;
   set obj.http.location = "https://" + req.http.Host + req.url;
   
}

  return(deliver);
}
```

However, this seems to trigger for https requests instead of http. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using syntax from an extremely old version of Varnish.

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/redirect/ for an official tutorial on HTTP to HTTPS redirection.

Here's a code snippet from that tutorial that allows you to redirect HTTP to HTTPS:

```
vcl 4.1;

import proxy;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = 8080;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if ((req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto && req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto != "https") || 
        (req.http.Scheme && req.http.Scheme != "https")) {
        return (synth(750));
    } elseif (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto && !req.http.Scheme && !proxy.is_ssl()) {
        return (synth(750));
    }
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 750) {
        set resp.status = 301;
        set resp.http.location = "https://" + req.http.Host + req.url;
        set resp.reason = "Moved";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```